# How to match HTML header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, scripting

I have the following script, where I parse entire HTML and bind to a div (Homepage):

```
function htmlResponse() {
    var res = "";
    debugger;
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        options.async = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:1469/Home.aspx",
        success: function (result) {
            res = result;
            res = res.replace(/\/CMSPages\/GetResource\.ashx/g, 'http://localhost:1469/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx');
            res = res.replace(/\/WebResource\.axd/g, 'http://localhost:1469/WebResource.axd');
            res = res.replace('<ul>', '<ul class="fallback browse-experience-drop-down-width">');

            $("#homePage").html(res);
        }
    }).done(function () {

    });
};
```

`res` variable contains full HTML which needs to be binds to div homepage.

How I can write another regex which will fetch only `<HEADER>` till `</HEADER>` and `<FOOTER>` till `</FOOTER>`?

And bind those two sections in two div tags?

Something like below:

```
header = res.regex("REGEX FOR FETCHING HEADER");
footer = res.regex("REGEX FOR FETCHING FOOTER");

                $("#HEADER").html(header);
                $("#FOOTER").html(footer);
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: i know, but we have a situation here, because we are trying to integrate a CMS website to external website, which cms wont supports integration to external sites, hence need to parse and change the source and load

Comment: @SmartestVEGA — So *parse* it. You're already using jQuery which will do that for you.

Comment: how i do that, can you give some reference, i checked it in internet and didn't got any relevant one

Comment: AFAIK, it should get parsed automatically unless the CMS is sticking out the wrong content-type, in which case you can force it with `dataType: "html"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

For header:

```
/<(?:HEADER|header)>([\s\S]*?)<\/(?:HEADER|header)>/g
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS5fG5/1)

For footer:

```
/<(?:footer|FOOTER)>([\s\S]*?)<\/(?:footer|FOOTER)>/g
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ0tJ7/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
/<HEADER>(\n.*)*<\/HEADER>/g
```

should do the trick.